# Smooth proper varieties over the integers that are not toric

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, toric-varieties, p-adic-hodge-theory

Does there exist a smooth proper variety $X$ over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ that is not toric?

By Fontaine, we know that there is no Abelian scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$. Also by Fontaine, we know that any such $X$ has $H^p(X,\Omega^q) = 0$ for $p+q \leq 3, p\neq q$ (but I might be misquoting this theorem).

Moreover, I think it's easy to find examples of toric varieties that are smooth proper over $\mathbb Z$. For instance, I believe this includes $\mathbb P^n$, projective bundles over it, blow ups of such and the Hilbert scheme of points on a surface of this kind. Are there any other examples known?

Comment: Yes, quadrics .

Comment: Or more generally flag varieties $G/P$. (I think they are toric iff they are isomorphic to a projective space).